# Ubuntu 15.04 on laptop - "When plugged in" setting not enforced after battery is charged to 100%

Tags: 15.04, suspend, laptop, power-management, battery

I got Ubuntu 15.04 running on a Dell 3147. Under Power settings, I have **When plugged in** set to **Don't suspend**. It seems that after the battery has reached 100% it no longer honors this setting, instead dropping down to the **On battery power** setting (which I have set for 20 minutes).

Any thoughts?

Is there any way I can say "when plugged in OR at 100%"?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu and Batteries do not co-operate very well. I would suggest trying out TLP. I have found TLP to solve few of my Battery related issues from 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS on Dell Latitude Series.

**Look the accepted and thoroughly written Answer here:** 
[Is there a power saving application similar to Jupiter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter) (Its too long to repeat, nor I wish to take credit for it -It helped me a lot)

Installing:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
```

Removing:

```
sudo apt-get remove tlp
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:linrunner/tlp
```

Links to TLP Official Site for Further and extra information how set/edit/modify/configure TLP and its functions.

http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html

**I highly recommend to read the above post and Linrunner TLP Guide.**